# How to root Samsung J1 Ace?

Tags: rooting

I have tried with many apps but none of them help to root Samsung J1 Ace (SM-J110H).

Is there any successful method to root Samsung J1 Ace (SM-J110H) smart phone?

Comment: Did you try this?: **[(ROOT) (RECOVERY) Samsung galaxy J1 ACE - SM-J110H](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-j/development/root-recovery-samsung-galaxy-j1-ace-sm-t3364041)**

Comment: is it is a rooting method?

Comment: Yes. Follow the instructions there.

Comment: how to decide that which file i want to download for my device cyanogen,cwm-6,3.0.0

Comment: Use the first one: TWRP

Comment: can i increase size of ram after root the phone

Comment: If your kernel supports swap memory, yes, you can. Else flash a custom kernel that supports it.

Answer (score 0):

Download Odin, SuperSU.zip and twrp for the j110h. Then be sure to enable adb debugging and OEM unlock in developer options. Then reboot into download mode. Plug into PC start Odin, choose the correct twrp and click start and at the same time hold down vol up and home button, I'm thinking g when I flashed this recovery I had to hold the vol up and home while it appeared to restart a couple times but it did work. When twrp finally boots it should mount on the PC and then transfer the SuperSU zip and then flash it.